# AFNetworking and array post

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am trying to POST an array of strings to my server:

```
NSMutableArray *test = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(Contact *x in numbers){
    [test addObject:x.number];
}


NSDictionary *params = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
params = @{@"token" : v1_Token,
           @"numbers" : test
          };

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

@try{
     NSString *url = API_URL;
     url =[url stringByAppendingString:@"retrieve"];
     [manager POST:url parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(responseObject);

      } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
              NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
      }];
}
@catch(NSException * e){
    //error
}
```

x.numbers outputs a string variable

My raw post data should look like this:

```
{
"token": "0r1x0002W53Nk1zD889868P1QJ11Us88",
"numbers": ["5555555555","9055550000"]
}
```

The problem is I cant seem to get it to display like that.

Comment: How is it displaying?, I mean if you log that var.

Comment: `xcode` log isn't like things in real life :/ u should sniff (using `Charles` or anything else) for more info.

Comment: When I do `NSLog(@"%@", test)` I get the following results: `(
    5555555555,
    9055550000
)`

Comment: What make u think that iOS NSDictionary and JSON goes side by side?! Why `params = @{@"token" : v1_Token,
           @"numbers" : test
          };` ??
U should build your own `JSON`. What r u trying to do? because what u did is adding a params to the `URL`. R u trying to `http` post request with body?

Comment: I was just testing and seeing if it worked. I couldn't find anything online so I came here with what I had.

Comment: Yeah I am trying to put RAW post data in a POST request. I've used this method before and it worked.